# Diff between files in different directories

Tags: script, shell-script, zsh, diff

I have the follow directory structure

```
./goodboys/a.txt
./goodboys/b.txt
./badboys/a.txt.boy
./badboys/b.txt.boy
```

I am using zsh. I want to diff all *.txt in goodboys with *.txt.boy in badboys.

I am not looking for all possible diffs,
I need diffs between 
    ./goodboys/a.txt and ./badboys/a.txt.boy
    ./goodboys/b.txt and ./badboys/b.txt.boy

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using bash this is waht you need, change it for zsh:

`for i in $( ls ./goodboys ); do`

```
diff ./goodboys/$i ./badboys/$i".boy"
```

`done`